# ImageView doesn't adhere to layout rules when image is set

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm setting an image on a relative layout which is scaled. However when the image is set, the layout alignment rules are broken.  The image is supposed to align to the left hand side, but shifts.  The larger the image the further from the left hand edge the image is placed.  Other layout items like text that rely on the placement of the image also move.  The scaled image looks fine apart from its placement.

The image is 200px, the actual size of the bar's height is 70dp.  I could resize the image but id like to know why this happens.

EDIT - I have also tried setting the image dynamically `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:layout_above="@id/username"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@id/username"
            android:text="user name test"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play_media_btn_toggle"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@id/play"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of this problem?

Comment: Have you set `adjustViewBounds` on your imageview? This might be the problem.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer that fixed it thanks!  If you reply I will set that as correct answer.  I saw the documentation for this but didn't really understand what the attribute did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `adjustViewBounds` of your `ImageView` to `true` might fix your problem. By default, `ImageViews` don't scale their bounds when their  content gets scaled, creating a messed up layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your image dynamically, when your image resizes your holder is not set to fit the image so you have some weird disproportional gaps on one side (either width or height). You need to do this dynamically so you would avoid any gaps.

EDIT: here is an example how I scale the image (to fit the width) and then set it to holder and resize holder accordingly, this way I control the width of Holder and Image and ImageView (holder) scale type is Center.

```
float scaleFactor = (float)rssLayout.getWidth() / (float)bitmap.getWidth();     
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(bitmap.getWidth() * scaleFactor), (int)(bitmap.getHeight() * scaleFactor), true);
    bannerImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bannerImage.getLayoutParams();             
    params.width = bitmap.getWidth();
    params.height = bitmap.getHeight();
    bannerImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: Hey Marko, I originally set the image dynamically, which lead me to investigate the issue `imageView.setImageResource(placeholder_id);`, this produces the same issue